# MUI DatePicker show only month, and not year or day

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a date picker to my application, but the one to show only year and the other one only month something like this:
[image]

but so far with MUI DatePicker I have accomplished something like that, which shows month, day and year which I dont want to:

[image]

and heres my code:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <Stack spacing={3}>
                <DatePicker
                    views={['year']}
                    label="Year"
                    value={value}
                    disableFuture
                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                        setValue(newValue);
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />
                    )}
                />
                <DatePicker
                    views={['month']}
                    label="Month"
                    openTo="month"
                    disableFuture
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                        setValue(newValue);
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />
                    )}
                />
            </Stack>
        </LocalizationProvider>
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: On the one hand, it is not the goal of a DatePicker. On the other hand, why don't you create a selector with twelve values, from January to Decemer? It would be less confusing for the user.

Comment: that's true, didnt think of a selector and should be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You can make custom value for your `input`:
Like:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
   <Stack spacing={3}>
      <DatePicker
         views={['month']}
         label="Year"
         value={value}
         disableFuture
         onChange={(newValue) => {
             setValue(newValue);
         }}
         renderInput={(params) => (
             <TextField
                 {...params}
                 helperText={null}
                 // Here the line:
                 inputProps={{
                    ...params.inputProps,
                    value: value === null ? '' : value.getMonth()+1
                 }}
             />
         )}
      /> 
   </Stack>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Or whatever what you want to be shown as a value.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this property inputFormat="MMMM"

```js
 <DatePicker
                    views={['month']}
                    inputFormat="MMMM"
                    label="Month"
                    openTo="month"
                    disableFuture
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                        setValue(newValue);
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />
                    )}
                />
```